# "index "8" is out of valid range ' 0 to 1' for possibly stack overloaded array". How would I fix this?

Tags: c++

This is the function, what seems to not be working is probably some syntax that I got wrong in relation to making the array. It also says something about readable bytes being 8 but that 12 may read.

```
int sum = 0;
std::string total;
std::string space = " ";
cout << "Enter numbers:\n"; 

int array[2] = { 0, 0 };

int i; 
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {

    std::cin >> array[i];
    int size = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < 0; z++) {

        array[i] /= 10;

        size++;
    }


    for (int b = 0; b < size; b++) {


        int multiplication = 0;

        multiplication = array[i] % 10;
        multiplication *= size;
        sum += multiplication;
        array[i] /= 10;
    }




    total += std::to_string(sum);
    total.append(space);


}

std::cout << total;
```

Comment: can you please post the error message

Comment: `sizeof(array)` returns 8 you need `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)` = 2

Comment: Use range based for-loops. They provide an excellent way to avoid this problem: `for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) { std::cin >> array[i]; ...` becomes `for(int& v : array) { std::cin >> v; ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::size(array)` since C++17. This returns N, the count of elements in C++ array declared as `T array[N]`. To get `std::size` you need to include the header file of any C++ standard container, for example `#include <array>`. See [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size, **in bytes** of its argument.  If you want the size **in elements** of an array, you must divide by the size of the data type as well:

The size, in elements, of an array `arr` of `T` is `sizeof arr/sizeof(T)`.

C++17 and later support `std::size` which will return the size of an array in elements.